# String in a query

Tags: query, string

I am trying to run the following query locator:

```
 Database.getQueryLocator('select ' + TrackingNumberString + ',Carrier_Status__c from ' 
                         + MainObjectString + ' where ECS__Shipped_Time__c = LAST_N_DAYS:' 
                         + DaysBackString + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + exclusion1);
```

Where:

```
TrackingNumberString = Tracking_Number_Field__c

MainObjectString = Main_Object__c

DaysBackString = 1

and exclusion1 = Delivered
```

The fields are correct, and I cannot simply insert 'Main_Object__c' into the query string because it is located from another query using a custom setting.  Also it isn't really related to my question.

I am getting the following error:

> 12:20:07:059 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: Variable does not
>   exist: Delivered

So my question is:  How can I write the code so that 'and Carrier_Status__c' does not equal the string: Delivered?

Should I do something where I extract the string information from Carrier_Status__c then run it through a series of if statements to see if it equals exclusion1?  Or is there some way to type it in a query so that Carrier_Status__c does not equal the string value of exclusion1?

Any help is appreciated. If you need more code to help, just ask please.

Comment: `exclusion1` needs to be quoted in the dynamic soql; i.e. it must be generated as `'Delivered'`

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap your value in single quotes. Replace `exclusion1` with `'\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion1) + '\''`.